# UICollectionView ScrollToItem With Insets

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a horizontally scrolling `uicollectionview` with insets I am setting through the `uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout` method `insetForSectionAt`.

In trying to use the method `.scrollToItem` the scroll doesn't seem to take into account of the inset and only scrolls a part of the way.

Is there a suggested approach to account for the inset and have the scroll go all the way? It is just one section and I am trying to scroll from item 0 to item 1.

Comment: Not sure if I got your issue, however [setContentOffset(_:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619400-setcontentoffset) might be useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to manually modify content offset based on a custom calculation.

```
let customPoint = CGPoint(x: customX, y: customY)
collectionView.setContentOffset(customPoint, animated: true)
```

Where customX and customY are calculated based on cell size and cell count + other factors such as insetForSection.